# How to resolve DPDK mempool creation fail?

Tags: c, dpdk

I am stuck at using `rte_mempool_create`, whatever configure I give, the function just return `NULL`.

Below is my code,

```
int main(argc, **argv) {
        int ret;
        ret = rte_eal_init(argc, argv);
        if (ret < 0)
                printf("eal init fail!!!\n");
        unsigned lcore_id;
        lcore_id = rte_lcore_id();
        printf("lcore %u\n", lcore_id);

        struct rte_mempool *mp;
        mp = rte_mempool_create("MP", 1024,
                                32, 32, 0,
                                NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                                0, 0);
        if (NULL == mp) {
                printf("mempool init fail\n");
                return -1;
        }
        printf("mempool init pass\n");

        rte_mempool_free(mp);
        printf("mempool uninit pass\n");
        return 0;
}
```

And running result,

```
EAL: Detected 96 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 4 NUMA nodes
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: No available hugepages reported in hugepages-32768kB
EAL: No available hugepages reported in hugepages-64kB
EAL: No available hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
lcore 0
mempool init fail
```

How to get pool correctly created?

Comment: there are couple things that are missed out, such as DPDK version, Platform, whether huge page is present on NUMA0 since you getting from SOCKET_ID0, 3rd arg number cache elements vs lcore thread should be less than 1024. Important factor is to use `rte_strerror(rte_errno))` to figure out reason of failure. I will wait for your edit in the question rather than marking as `insufficent data`. Please refer http://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__mempool_8h.html#a503f2f889043a48ca9995878846db2fd.

Comment: can you please the question with relevant information? Also note `https://stackoverflow.com/users/4350586/dmitry-grigoryev` has rejected the edit by removing `pool`. It has been already cited in the edit comments the issue related to DPDK and dpdk libraries usage. @dmitry-grigoryev please share your thought why this is not DPDK issue.

Comment: @VipinVarghese Finally I got this work, so the version is 20.11, ARM platform, hugepage  `echo 256 > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages`. The problem is cross compile, that is to say, I compiled on ARM and used on x86, then fail... After rearrange the toolchain it works fine, including **pool free**. Thanks for guiding the direction :)

Comment: good to hear that it is build issue and not DPDK issue. Please accept or upvote to close the ticket .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no issue with DPDK code or libraries. Modified the code snippet and tested with the following configuration

- DPDK version: 19.11.5 LTS
- CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4, 88 threads
- Huge Page: Hugepagesize:    1048576 kB, HugePages_Total:      16, HugePages_Free:       15
- command: ./build/test

[EDIT-1] as updated in the comment from @LinconFive, the issue was the huge page not set for the right NUMA (ignoring the cross compile as arm binary will not run on x86)

**test result: Pass**

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/queue.h>

#include <rte_memory.h>
#include <rte_launch.h>
#include <rte_eal.h>
#include <rte_per_lcore.h>
#include <rte_lcore.h>
#include <rte_debug.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int ret;
        ret = rte_eal_init(argc, argv);
        if (ret < 0)
                printf("eal init fail!!!\n");
        unsigned lcore_id;
        lcore_id = rte_lcore_id();
        printf("lcore %u\n", lcore_id);

        struct rte_mempool *mp;
        mp = rte_mempool_create("MP", 1024,
                                32, 32, 0,
                                NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                                0, 0);
        if (NULL == mp) {
                printf("mempool init fail\n");
                return -1;
        }
        printf("mempool init pass\n");

        while(1);

        rte_mempool_free(mp);
        printf("mempool uninit pass\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Logs:

```
lcore 0
mempool init pass
```

note:

- there were multiple requests made to @LinconFive on the version, platform and specific error, as I suspect the platform and configuration.
- There is no issue with DPDK code or library.